# Link to order in magento admin

Tags: magento-1.9, grid

I have developed custom  grid which shows list of orders placed by customers.I also want to set hyper link to the particular order in sales-> order tab please help me to achieve this.

Answer (score 6):

In your `Grid.php`.

```
public function getRowUrl($order)
{
    return $this->getUrl(
        'adminhtml/sales_order/view',
        array(
            'order_id' => $order->getId()
        )
    );
}
```

Comment: In a more general sense, you can always do: 

Mage::helper('adminhtml')->getUrl('adminhtml/sales_order/view', array('order_id' => $order->getId()));